# Algebraic K-groups and braids

Tags: algebraic-k-theory, braid-groups, gr.group-theory, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

This is (I think) a reference request:

Are there calculations of any algebraic K-groups for the (group ring of) the Artin braid groups?

Comment: Perhaps you should tag it as reference-request then.

Answer (score 2):

A result regarding the Whitehead group, reduced projective class group  and the lower K-groups of the group ring of the Artin 
braid groups is here [link text](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=roushon&vfpref=html&r=11&mx-pid=1759505)

Comment: The link is password protected :(

Comment: @Dr Shello Roushon's link goes to the mathscinet review. See if you can access this: http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2000/10/515.full.pdf+html

Comment: Ah, looks like that's locked, too! But this link to the article works: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~roushon/iso.html